# How to copy dynamically allocated array of struct?

Tags: c, struct, memcpy, dynamically-generated

I have been struggling with this. What I have found here on stackoverflow, and other places was to just do:

```
memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof(b));
```

But for me, that did not work. So I thought, I share what worked for me without any unexpected behavior.

Comment: sizeof(b) will tell you the size of the pointer, not the size of the memory block that b points to.  So, your line of code will only copy 4 or 8 bytes depending on the system architecture (32 or 64 bit).  You need to pass the 3rd parameter to memcpy to really say how much memory to copy.

Comment: yes, I have realized/understood/read that by now :), but for some reason this is what I find as accepted solution for questions :/.

Comment: You need to show where `a` and `b` came from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case previous solutions did not work properly, e.g. the one in the question!  (it copied about half of only the first element).
So in case, somebody needs a solution, that will give you correct results, here it is:

```
memcpy(a, b, n * sizeof(*b));
```

**More detail:**

```
int i, n = 50; 
struct YourStruct *a, *b;

a = calloc(n, sizeof(*a));
b = malloc(n * sizeof(*b));
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) { 
    // filling a
}

memcpy(b, a, n * sizeof(*a)); // <----- memcpy 'n' elements from 'a' to 'b'

if (a != NULL) free(a); // free 'a'
a = calloc(2*n, sizeof(*a)); // 'a' is size 2n now

memcpy(a, b, n * sizeof(*b)); // <------ memcpy back the 'n' elements from 'b' to 'a'

// do other stuff with 'a' (filling too)...
```

Some notes:

- I used calloc for a, because in the '// filling a' part I was doing
  operations that required initialized data.
- I could have used realloc as well.
- I was kind of doing a dynamically growing array (with doubling size -> log(n)), but here I simplified it.
- You should check, if memory allocation is successful or not (a,b NULL or not). But here, I removed those checks for simplification.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it was malloc before, and I just copied it. That caused the typo.

Comment: the posted code can result in a seg fault event if either the `calloc()` or the `malloc()` fails.   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from any memory allocation function (malloc, calloc, realloc) before using that value

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but this is just a simplified version, which tries to show usage of memcpy.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have:

```
#define N 42
struct struct_name *a = malloc(sizeof *a * N);  // allocate N objects
struct struct_name *b = malloc(sizeof *b * N);  // allocate N objects
```

then the correct `memcpy` call to copy the array of structure objects is:

```
memcpy(a, b, sizeof *a * N);
```